# Changing tabs using Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm in trouble because the tabs that I'm trying to change using Meteor isn't working correctly. I have the same code using just HTML + CSS (Bootstrap) + jQuery and it works fine. But when I put it into my Meteor app, the tabs doesn't change correctly, it changes just one time when I press the button "Next" on the 1st tab.

I don't see any solution for this. This is my code without using Meteor:

```js
 $('.btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

In my Meteor App, I'm changing the Javascript to:

```js
Template.nameTemplate.events({

  "click .btnNext": function(){
    $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
  }

});
```

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is that Bootstrap automatically adds the event handlers on elements with `data-toggle="tab"` when it first runs. Meteor renders the tabs in after bootstrap has run, meaning they don't get automatically instantiated.

This means you need to do it yourself. The [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) Have an example of doing so like this:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

For your example this means replacing `.click()` with `.tab('show')`in your event:

```
Template.nameTemplate.events({
  "click .btnNext": function(e){
    $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").tab("show");
  }
});
```